# How To Check Which Stored Procedure Query Is Running Sql Server Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

i am trying to run one query at a time fist it check user name if not exsis then it insert that value i want to know how would i know on code behind code that which query it execute my code behind code is ,

```
 public int CreateUser(string UserName,string Pwd)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateUser", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter name = cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            name.Value = UserName;
            SqlParameter password = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            password.Value = Pwd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adpt.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            return 0;
        }
```

my stored procedure is ,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserName varchar(200) = NULL,
    @Password varchar(200) = NULL  

AS


IF NOT EXISTS(select * from[dbo].[User] where
             [dbo].[User].User_Name=@UserName)
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into [dbo].[User] (User_Name,User_Password,User_Type)
    values (@UserName,@Password,'User')
END
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Comment: hi, may i know what's the purpose of knowing it? do you want to know if a new user is created or not?

Comment: it purpose is to populate message box that user has created or not

Comment: What was the error in this. will you be please enumerate?

Answer (score 0):

You can do SELECT @@IDENTITY or SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() at the end of your procedure to return the inserted ID. if the value is NULL, then no record has been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
    public int CreateUser(string UserName,string Pwd)
    {
        int intRowsinserted = 0;

        cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateUser", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter name = cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        name.Value = UserName;
        SqlParameter password = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        password.Value = Pwd;

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        intRowsinserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        conn.Close();

        return intRowsinserted;
    }
```

**First**, adpt.Fill(ds) should be used when we want to return dataset. **Second**, cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() should be used to perform insert, update, or delete operation on a table and it will return number of rows inserted, updated, or deleted. **Third**, for more detail refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

**Please mark this answer useful if this solve your problem.**